# Chrome new tabs crash when opening

Tags: macos, google-chrome, tabs, windows-10

I encountered something like a bug in Chrome and am searching for workarounds or an explanation of the following behaviour:

I usually have a lot of tabs open in chrome, distributed on a hand full of windows. Sometimes, most of the chrome tabs I open crash. Their content is gray and they have a sad smiley as icon (no error message). This affects some tabs, even system tabs, but not all. Usually, duplicating a tab works fine. To watch youtube videos, I take the working tab of a video and copy the url. If the url is on the same site, it may work. To open the StackOverflow site for example, I duplicated an open BlendExchange tab and clicked on a StackOverflow question in the siderail.

This error can easily be fixed by restarting Chrome, but sooner or later it will restart bugging and reopening ~60 Tabs at the risk of loosing them is quite annoying.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. It is not profile-specific. I tried removing  the Hangouts app, which seemed to reduce the frequency but it is still occurring.

Comment: same here, started happening recently, especially for "Open link in new tab".